# Java: basis rest-service standalone

Tags: java, rest

I want to implement a REST service in Java.

I should not be a servlet (no need of jetty, jersey, glassfish, tomcat).

I would love a simple jar-file that includes a standalone http-server I can call and implement my handlers. Should support HTTPS, Basic-Auth and JSON - no need for SOAP.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can [embed Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/embedding-jetty.html) and use it like a standalone HTTP server (without all the Servlet stuff). Embedded Jetty is a perfect web server to use something like this. It does a good job of the HTTP stuff, without the load of Java EE.

If Jetty doesn't work for you, try [Netty](https://netty.io/). I haven't used Netty personally, but I have heard that it is great. It should have the same features as Embedded Jetty

Answer (score 1):

You can create a spring boot application which has in-built tomcat server and you can easily write the rest service with minimum configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it with grizzly that is - as far I understood - more or less part of Jersey. But it would work with others too.